# Ошибка 0xc0000005 как исправить?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Когда я начинаю запускать свой движок на библиотеке OpenGL консоль мне выдает ошибку:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe995ec53a, pid=1312, tid=8216
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (21.0.1+12) (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
Problematic frame:
C  [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0xc53a]

No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\Users\������\eclipse-workspace\find_the_kolobki_alpha1\hs_err_pid1312.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

код движка:

```
public Maincode() {
    instance = this;
}

public void run() {
    this.init();
}
public void init() {
    this.window = new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, game_title);
    RenderEngine.init();
    this.window.windowcode();
    this.shader = new Shader("res/shaders/sh.vert", "res/shaders/sh.frag");
    this.texture = new Texture("res/textures/findthekolobkilogo.png");
    
    this.shader.bind();
    this.shader.setUnifromInt("u_TextureSampler", 0);
    
    this.update();
}
public void update() {
    int[] indices = {0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3};
    float[] vertices = 
    {
    //      pos               colours                       uv
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
           -0.5f,  0.5f, 0,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
           -0.5f, -0.5f, 0,   1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f 
    };
    
    VertexArrayObject vertexArray = new VertexArrayObject();
    VertexBufferObject vertexBuffer = new VertexBufferObject(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.setLayout(new BufferLayout(
            new VertexAttribute("attrib_Position", ShaderDataType.t_float3),
            new VertexAttribute("attrib_Colour", ShaderDataType.t_float4),
            new VertexAttribute("attrib_TextureCoord", ShaderDataType.t_float2)
        ));
    vertexArray.putBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    IndexBufferObject indexBuffer = new IndexBufferObject(indices);
    vertexArray.putBuffer(indexBuffer);
    
    GameObj gameObj = new GameObj(new Vector3f(0,0,0), new Vector3f(0,0,0), new Vector3f(1,1,1));
    gameObj.setModel(vertexArray);
    gameObj.setTexture(texture);
    
    while(!this.window.isclosereq()) {
        RenderEngine.begin(shader);
        {
            RenderEngine.RGO(gameObj, shader);
        }
        RenderEngine.end(shader);
        this.window.updatewindow();
    }
    RenderEngine.destroy();
    this.window.destroywindow();
}
public static void addAttribute(int attributeId, VertexAttribute attribute,
         int bufferStride)
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeId);
    glVertexAttribPointer
    (
        attributeId,
        attribute.gEAS(),
        attribute.convertedType,
        attribute.normalized ? true : false,
        bufferStride,
        attribute.offset
    );
}
public static Maincode get() {
    return instance;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Maincode().run();
}
public Window getWindow() {
    return this.window;
}
```

Когда я закрываю строку `RenderEngine.init()` в комментарий, ошибка пропадает.

Что мне делать?

Comment: `An error report file with more information is saved as` - наверно, надо начать с просмотра этого лога.

Comment: 0xc0000005 обычно появляется, если есть проблемы с доступом к памяти (обращение к месту, где ничего нет, либо некорректный блок памяти). Точно всё инициализируете и подгружаете для работы с gl?